# Invalid input : expected ")", "WHERE", "{" or a parameter (line 3, column 19 (offset: 184))... I'm following the guide so what is happening?

Tags: database, csv, graph, neo4j

I'm just trying from such a CSV file

```
"metaphor","entailmentDescription","example","sourceFrame","targetFrame","isASourceSubcaseOf"
metaphor1,escription,example,sf,tf,sbsbs
```

To map it to a graph database with this command I'm seeing from the tutorial

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///Query(8).csv' AS row
WITH row[0] AS metaphor, row[1] AS entailmentDescription, row[2] AS example, row[3] AS sourceFrame, row[4] AS targetFrame
MERGE (p:Metaphor {metaphor: metaphor})
  SET p.entailmentDescription= entailmentDescription, p.example= example, p.sourceFrame= sourceFrame, p.targetFrame= targetFrame
RETURN count(p);
```

I'm not really understanding the error

Comment: I don't get an error from your query (in neo4j 5.15). What version are you using? Also, your query has a logical error, since you are treating the header row as a data row. This query fixes that: `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Query(8).csv' AS r
MERGE (p:Metaphor {metaphor: r.metaphor})
SET p.entailmentDescription=r.entailmentDescription, p.example=r.example, p.sourceFrame=r.sourceFrame, p.targetFrame=r.targetFrame
RETURN count(p);`

Comment: I have a problem, curly brackets in windows are not shown in any way! I don't know what to do, not even copying and pasting works

Comment: If you have a question about the Windows OS, ask at [this site](https://superuser.com/).